# Passing Javascript Object to Function & changing text field

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

This is probably a stupid mistake that i have made; i am still new to web development so be nice please :)

Here i create the object

```
var crs0 = {ID:1, TITLE:"test", DESC:"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",ER:"a",LENGTH:"a", FEE:"a"};
```

Here i use an onclick event to call a function & pass the object as a parameter

```
<div class = "btnDC" onclick="display(crs0)">test</div>
```

Here is the function that i use to replace data in some textarea's & text inputs with properties from the object.

```
            function display(crs)
        {
            document.getElementById("ttl").value=crs.TITLE;
            document.getElementById("dsc").value=crs.DESC;
            document.getElementById("er").value=crs.ER;
            document.getElementById("lng").value=crs.LENGTH;
            document.getElementById("fees").value=crs.FEE;
            document.getElementById("ID").value=crs.ID;
        }
```

The onclick does nothing & i have no idea why. (Other javascript on the page does work so i haven't missed a semi-colon :D )

[Update 1]
All of the data is pulled from a database the code above is copied from the page it produces; i have done a few tweaks & i can get it to produce an alert box for the display function however if i try & make it show any data of the object within that alert box it doesn't display anything (i hate not having a debugger), which suggests that the object isn't being passed.
Here is the PHP code i use to create the onclick

```
echo '<div class = "btnDC" onclick="display(crs'.$n.')">'.$inf['TITLE'][$n].'</div>
```

Could that be the issue? 
it produces this line of code

```
<div class = "btnDC" onclick="display(crs0)">test</div>
```

---

As mentioned the code i have shown works (thanks juvian);
I generated this code from php & although the javascript generated was correct there was a problem with some of the php, i didn't find the exact problem but i have re-written most of the php & now it works.

Comment: works, fine, you are probably doing something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/m2R9T/

Comment: thanks, i have updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned the code i have shown works (thanks juvian); I generated this code from php & although the javascript generated was correct there was a problem with some of the php, i didn't find the exact problem but i have re-written most of the php & now it works.